# Setting Permissions and Visibilty for Users in Sandbox then pushing changes to Production?

Tags: permissions, visibility

I am making some layout changes to the Account, Contact, and Opportunity pages in sandbox and would like to set permissions in some way so that all users can view all accounts/fields/pages but can only edit accounts that are owned by them.  Is there a way to do this in one overall setting or does it have to be done for each of the Pages?  Also how does this have to be set up in the sandbox in order to later push it to Production?

Comment: So should I use the "Controlled by Parent" setting for the 3 Account, Contact,and Opportuntity objects in OWD to enable all users to see everything but only edit accounts and etc. that they own?

Answer (score 1):

Check OWD (Org Wide Setting) in salesforce.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sharing_model_fields.htm&language=en_US

For your particular case say you want everyone but  the owner to edit the accounts set OWD on Account object to public read only(Look at the doc to fine tune the visibility to set per object)

You can create all the fields, add the fields to the page layout and create a change set and push this to Production from a sandbox, and then adjust the OWD setting in production as you did in the sandbox environment.

Comment: And add the profiles to the change set.

Comment: So should I use the "Controlled by Parent" setting for the 3 Account, Contact,and Opportuntity objects in OWD to enable all users to see everything but only edit accounts and etc. that they own?

Comment: You can set  the account as public read only and set the other 2 as controlled by parent. If you do it this way understand that only the account owner can edit the contact and oppty associated with the account. If you want to keep all three objects independent of the other 2 setting, set all three to public read only, so that if there are different owners the three objects they can still edit the corresponding records.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, this could be done [using a change set](https://www.panaya.com/blog/salesforce/salesforce-change-sets/) from sandbox to production. Alternatively, [changes like this can be made directly in live](https://www.panaya.com/blog/salesforce/salesforce-sandbox/). You can add custom fields directly in live. Just remember to check that lead mapping is set up for any field where it applies. Permissions are also safe to change directly in production. Just be sure to make changes to a specific user’s permission set rather than an entire profile.

*Full Disclosure: I work for panaya.com. We recently wrote a comprehensive [blog post](https://www.panaya.com/blog/salesforce/salesforce-sandbox/) that includes a cheat sheet on What Changes to Make in Live vs Salesforce Sandbox. You might find it useful.